# Duplication-Divergence network model

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks

I made this code for generating networks following the [duplication-divergence model](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0108043), in which we have to steps:

- duplication: a node i is selected at random. A new node i', with a link to all neighbors of i is created, and with a probability p, a link betwenn i and i' is established;
- divergence: for each of the nodes j linked to i and i' we choose randomly one of the two links (i,j) or (i',j) and remove it with probability q.

The code I have is the following:

```
  ddmodel[n_, p_, q_] /; n >= 3 := 
 Module[{g, vdeg, el, el2, node, newnode, links}, 
  g = ConstantArray[{}, n];
  g[[1 ;; 2]] = Table[AdjacencyList[CompleteGraph[2], j], {j, 2}];
  vdeg = ConstantArray[0, n];
  vdeg[[1 ;; 2]] = 1;
  Do[

   (*duplication*)
   node = RandomChoice[Range[j - 1]];
   g[[j]] = g[[node]];
   vdeg[[j]] = vdeg[[node]];
   If[RandomReal[] <= p,
    g[[node]] = Append[g[[node]], j];
    g[[j]] = Append[g[[j]], node];
    vdeg[[j]] += 1;
    vdeg[[node]] += 1;, Continue[]];

   (*divergence*)
   If[ RandomReal[] <= q,
    Do[vdeg[[k]] += 1;
        g[[k]] = Append[g[[k]], j], {k, 
         Flatten[Table[Drop[g[[node]], {l}], {l, #}]]}] &@
      RandomChoice[Range[Length[g[[node]]]]];
    ,
    Do[vdeg[[k]] += 1; g[[k]] = Append[g[[k]], j], {k, g[[node]]}];];
   , {j, 3, n}];

  Graph[Union[
    Map[Sort, Flatten[MapIndexed[Thread[{#2[[1]], #1}] &, g], 1]]]]]
```

The code works fine and quickly if i choose q=0.1 and p from 0.1 to 0.3. But since I have to test is for higher values, it is not working due to amount of time needed (in the order of days, for me).
The duplication part is ok, because when I set q=0 I can generate networks for values of p from 0.1 to 1.0. But when I have to introduce the divergence in my models, it is not satisfatory.
I already built the divergence code with some variations, but the results were the same.

Comment: The divergence step is not clear to me: Is it possible that `{i,j}` and `{i,jnew}` both remain? Or is it `{i,j}` with probability `q` and `{i,jnew}` with probability `1-q` that remains?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher yes, it is possible that they remain. The probability q is the probability that one random link will be deleted or no.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is my interpretation of the algorithm. It is still not very efficient, but it contains some minor improvements: First of all, removed the bookkeeping for `vdeg` since it hasn't been used. Second, I tried to generate as many random numbers at once as possible.

However, I could not get rid of any `Append` and `Delete` commands; they should be the main reasons for the slow performance.

```
ClearAll[f];
f[n_, p_, q_] /; n >= 3 := 
 Module[{g, i, j, gi, ginew, prand, qrand, irand, coinflips},
  irand = 1 + RandomInteger /@ Range[0, n];
  prand = RandomReal[{0, 1}, n];
  g = ConstantArray[{}, n];
  g[[1]] = {2};
  g[[2]] = {1};
  Do[
   i = irand[[inew-1]];
   gi = g[[i]];
   ginew = gi;
   qrand = RandomReal[{0, 1}, Length[gi]];
   coinflips = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, Length[gi]];
   Do[
    j = gi[[k]];
    If[qrand[[k]] <= q,
     If[coinflips[[k]] == 1,
       g[[j]] = g[[j]] /. i -> inew;
       gi = Delete[gi, k];
       ,
       ginew = Delete[ginew, k];
       ];
     ,
     g[[j]] = Append[g[[j]], inew];
     ]
    , {k, Length[gi], 1, -1}];

   If[prand[[inew]] <= p,
    AppendTo[gi, inew];
    AppendTo[ginew, i];
    ];

   g[[i]] = gi;
   g[[inew]] = ginew;
   ,
   {inew, 3, n}];

  DeleteDuplicates[
   Sort /@ Join @@ Table[Thread[{k, g[[k]]}], {k, 1, n}]]
  ]
```